# How should I do layout management with ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just starting a project with ASP.NET MVC 4, and I'm wondering how I should handle the layout management? I'm not very experienced with Web layout management in the first place, but I'm aware that [Blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org) is a popular option and that in the Rails world [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) would be a good bet. Should I just go with Blueprint? Is there anything I should be aware of as regards the integration with MVC 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as an alternative to what you self mentioned (Blueprint) I can strongly recommend **Bootstrap from Twitter** (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). I have been using this myself in projects with ASP.NET MVC 3 and ASP.NET web forms.

**Bootstrap from Twitter** is open source and you can find much information on the Internet (i.e many problems you may encounter have already been solved, just Google them). **Bootstrap from Twitter** "supports" many browsers (computers, smartphones and so on), big/small screens, jQuery...

Comment: Cool, I'll have a look at Bootstrap, tomorrow or so (bedtime).

Comment: OK, I'm sold. Bootstrap looks like exactly what I need so far.